# When using getElementsByTagNameNS() in Java how do you check to see if the node exists?

Tags: java, xml, dom

If i'm iterating through nested nodes and one of the nodes is there sometimes and others it's not how do I check for that so I don't get a NullPointerException?

For example if I'm doing something like this and it comes to a set where idNumber isn't there it throws a NullPointerException.

```
    <code>
       NodeList nl = docEle.getFirstChild().getChildNodes();
           int length = nl.getLength();
           System.out.println(length);
           for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
               if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                       idNumber = el.getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:example","idNumber").item(0).getTextContent();
           }
    </code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html#item(int)) is the javadoc for `NodeList.item()`, it says the following:

> The node at the indexth position in the NodeList, or null if that is not a valid index.

So, looks like there no node is found in your case and hence, `list` is empty. You can add a check before calling `getTextContent()` method, e.g.:

```
NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagNameNS("urn:example","idNumber");
if(list.getLength() > 0){
   idNumber = list.item(0).getTextContent();
}
```